# how to process the commands when using multiple pipes in C

Tags: c, shell, fork, pipe

I'm implementing a shell, and i got everything working perfectly fine. The problem im facing now is how to manage multiple pipes? for example ls -a -l -F | tr [a-z] [A-Z] | sort

question: I have this array and i want to separate the commands so i could process each process

```
args[0]= ls  
args[1]= -a  
args[3]= -l   
args[4]= -F  
args[5]= |  
args[6]= tr  
args[7]= [a-z]  
args[8]= [A-Z]  
args[9]= |  
args[10]= sort
```

how can i separate the commands everytime i find a '|'?  so i end up with something like this

```
    args1[0]= ls  
    args1[1]= -a  
    args1[3]= -l   
    args1[4]= -F 

    args2[0]= tr  
    args2[1]= [a-z]  
    args2[2]= [A-Z] 

    args3[0] = sort
```

Thank you so much for your help, any feedback is greatly appreciated

Comment: I just updated my question to focus more on this relevant problem

Comment: why don't you create an array of arrays? `args[0][0] = ls; args[0][1] = -a;` ... `args[1][0] = tr` ... `args[2][0] = sort`

Answer (score 2):

You'll need multiple pipes. Each pipe will take the stdout from process **n**, and feed it to the stdin of process **n+1**. You can't share pipes, otherwise your stdout will get interleaved between processes.

[This response](http://www.unix.com/showpost.php?p=302462332&postcount=2) to a similar question may be of use.

Comment: thanks for your response @brian I already have a basic idea on how to tackle this. Now my other issue is how to separate my args into for example: cmd[0]= ls , cmd[1]= -a, cmd[2]= -l, cmd[3]= -F and in another array nxt[0]= tr, nxt[1]= [a-z], nxt[2]= [A-Z], and in another one oth[0]= sort ??

Comment: because if im able to do that, i could totally implement the multiple piping

Comment: I would split on pipes *first* and then you'll have an array of strings representing commands and their arguments. You can then split further. Note that you have to worry about quoting e.g. what happens if you put pipes within quotes as, perhaps, an argument to a command ?